# Problem handling Exception with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I'm new to the Spring universe so i decided to try something simple to learn it.
i tryed to create a simple rest api with simple crud operations. The problem comes out trying to handle the different type of exceptions.

I tryed to handle the exception in the @RestController class with this function:

```
@ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @GetMapping(value = "userino/{id}")
    public User getUserino(@PathVariable long id){
        Optional<User> u = userRepo.findById(id);

        if(u.isPresent())
            return u.get();
        
        throw new NotFoundException("Inexistent user "+id);
        
    }
```

but using the path "localhost:8080/userino/3" (User 3 doesn't exist) on postman i visualize the following message:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-03-16T14:46:10.041+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/userino/3"
}
```

How do i fix this? i just want to visualize my own Error message.
thx to evryone

i expet to visualize my own txt error nt the default one.

Comment: Take out '@ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class) & '@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handler need a parameter same as your exception:

```
@ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
public Response handleException(NotFoundException e) {
    return new Response(e.getMessage());
}
```